# isPossibleNumber vs. isValidNumber

Tags: java, phone-number, libphonenumber, phonenumberutils

I am using Google's libphonenumber library to validate phone numbers on the server-side and I noticed that `PhoneNumberUtil` has two methods for doing this: `isPossibleNumber` and `isValidNumber`. What is the difference between them and when should I be using one rather than the other one?

Answer (score 19):

You can find their difference in their github page.

> isPossibleNumber - quickly guessing whether a number is a possible phonenumber by using only the length information, much faster than a full validation.
>
> isValidNumber - full validation of a phone number for a region using length and prefix information.

Comment: This means that using both isPossibleNumber and isValidNumber is more performant than just using isValidNumber alone if you have invalid numbers in your list?